# SonarQube - Can't resolve path generated in coverage file

Tags: python, sonarqube, pytest, sonarqube-scan

I have a problem where SonarQube is not able to parse the coverage reports , generated by pytest-cov. I have gone through StackOverflows posts and also the documentation on SQ, and have tried various options, but nothing works. Can someone tell me what is it that I am missing?

This is my project structure-

[image]

So, my root, contains a folder called "workflows", which in turn contains two subfolders , which are workflows and test. Now my source code is in `ProjectRoot/workflows/workflows` (highlighted in yellow in the screenshot of my project directory structure above) and my tests are in `ProjectRoot/workflows/tests`.

My `.coveragec` file, looks like

```
[run]
branch = True
source = workflows
relative_files = True

[report]
exclude_lines =
    if self.debug:
    pragma: no cover
    raise NotImplementedError
    if __name__ == .__main__.:

ignore_errors = True
omit =
    tests/*
    setup.py
    # this file is autogenerated by dbx
    workflows/common.py
skip_empty = True
```

Now when I run pytest in my build pipeline (Azure devops), I do it with a bash script like

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/workflows
python3 -m pytest tests/unit --cov --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov-report xml --junitxml pytests.xml
```

This generates a coverage file like

```
    <sources>
        <source>workflows</source>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package name="createexternaltables.tasks" line-rate="0" branch-rate="1" complexity="0">
            <classes>
                <class name="createtables.py" filename="createexternaltables/tasks/createtables.py" complexity="0" line-rate="0" branch-rate="1">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line number="2" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="4" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="7" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="10" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="12" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="13" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="14" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="19" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="20" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="22" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="24" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="25" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="31" hits="0"/>
                        <line number="32" hits="0"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </package>
```

In a subsequent step, I use `SonarQube` to analyze my source code (along with the coverage file generated by pytests

Here's how. If you notice I have set both the `projectBaseDir` and `sources`, since my tests and source code are inside subdirectories of the project root and not directly on the root

```
task: SonarQubePrepare@4
displayName: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
inputs:
   SonarQube: SonarQube
   scannerMode: CLI
   configMode: manual
   cliProjectKey: projectabc
   cliProjectName: projectabc
   cliProjectVersion: |
       $(Build.DefinitionName) $(Build.SourceBranchName) $(GitBuildVersionSimple)
   extraProperties: |
      sonar.projectBaseDir=./workflows
      sonar.language=py
      sonar.python.version=3.9
      sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=pytests.xml
      sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=workflows/coverage.xml
      sonar.sources=workflows/
      sonar.tests=tests/
```

I have tried with mutiple versions of the config, but no matter whatever, I do, I get the following error, when I do SonarQube Code Analyze.

```
Cannot resolve the file path 'createexternaltables/tasks/createtables.py' of the coverage report, the file does not exist in all 'source'.
```

What am I missing?